# Form Submission in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, target

Hi
I have another very strange problem.
I have a custom HTML form in wordpress page whose target is set to a page like "http://domain.com/contact-us/"
When when the form is submitted, it said "404-Nothing Found" even if the URL is same as the Contact page.

Any suggestions ???

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Does one of your form fields have a name attribute equal to "name" or "email"?

Wordpress seems to reserve some of these name attribute values and will push you out to a 404 page if you use them.  Thanks Wordpress!

Try prefixing all form fields with something to see if this is the problem

eg:

```
<input name="name" />
```

should become

```
<input name="test-name" />
```

Comment: this is the right answer. Thx James. You helped me a lot with this answer.